# Is the enumerator that ObjectSpace.each_object returns sorted by object creation time?

Tags: ruby

`ObjectSpace.each_object(ExampleClass)` returns an enumerator of all instances of ExampleClass. Is this enumerator guaranteed to be sorted by object creation time?

Comment: Why do you want to know? (Just curious.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm creating a class that sets @id for new instances based off the id of the last instance created. I could use class variables for this but generally they're considered bad practice (because they cary over in inheritances). I figured I could do this using `ObjectSpace.each_object(ExampleClass)[0]`.

Comment: The docs make no such guarantee, so I would assume that is an implementation detail, which could change.

Comment: *I could use class variables for this but generally they're considered bad practice (because they cary over in inheritances)*--So why can't you use a *class instance variable*?

Comment: @7stud well that has inheritance issues too since class instance variables aren't inherited at _all_, right?

Comment: I suppose it would work if I created class methods to set and return the class instance variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From very minimal testing it appears to be the case although as noted it could be implementation based and I would not recommend it in a production environment but

```
class R; end
m = 1000.times.map {R.new}
os = ObjectSpace.each_object(R).to_a
m.reverse.each_with_index.all? {|e,i| e === os[i]}
#=> true
```

Another issue with using `ObjectSpace` would be garbage collection. Once an object falls out of scope the GC will routine clean these up so you may lose a later object before an earlier one depending so I would not recommend this process as an accurate way of retaining the "id" you want.

Comment: I actually specifically chose ObjectSpace for this reason. I want to recycle ids which are no longer used by the program.

Comment: @rubyisfun you will only be "recycling" some of them and almost never in numerical order e.g. If #3 gets picked up by GC but #62 still exists then the next will be #63 based on your concept. Very rarely would these new objects end up incremental and even if they did the term id would be extremely misleading.

Comment: @rubyisfun if you really want to recycle them then it seems like wrapping their implementation in a management class or Module might make more sense an store the created objects in an Array. This way you will be able to find the holes in ids but again id will be somewhat misleading.

Comment: it will loop back after 999 if there are any available ids. I don't really care if the ids aren't recycled immediately. I want the next id to be the last id + 1 unless the last id was 999 @engineersmnky

Answer (score 2):

I think the more conventional way of doing that is something like this:

```
class A
  attr_reader :instance_id

  def initialize
    new_id = (self.class.last_instance_id || self.class.first_id-1) + 1
    self.class.instance_variable_set(:@last_instance_id, new_id)
    @instance_id = new_id 
  end

  def self.set_first_id(first_id)
    @first_id = id
  end

  singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, :first_id)
  singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, :last_instance_id)
end

A.first_id = 0       
a0 = A.new         #=> #<A:0x007fe2bb8c3de0 @instance_id=0> 
a0.instance_id     #=> 0

a1 = A.new         #=> #<A:0x007fe2bb8b87d8 @instance_id=1> 
a1.instance_id     #=> 1 

a2 = A.new         #=> #<A:0x007fe2bb8aa2c8 @instance_id=2> 
a2.instance_id     #=> 2 

A.last_instance_id #=> 2
```

Comment: Excellent XY answer. You could also contain the scope of the constant by placing it in the class. e.g. `class A; FIRST_ID = 0;...;end` this way if he wants similar functionality in other classes he doesn't have to come up with a ton of different terminology.

Comment: @engineersmnky, good points. I decided to make the method more robust by making the first id a class instance variable rather than a constant. "XY answer" is a nice touch, a needed term.

Comment: This is a good answer. In my case I want to recycle and cycle ids, so it's a little more complicated, but I can adapt this. I didn't think about having the instance create the class instance variable, instead of setting it directly in the class.